# How can I add icons Fontawesome in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How  can I add example 
this icon in React ?

//HTML

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

//script.js

```
render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement('span', {className: ''},
        React.createElement('i', {className:fa fa-address-book'})
 });
```

How  can I add icon fa fa-address-book in React ?

Comment: the className property value from the 'i' is missing a opening single quote. You are also missing the closing parenthesis for the first call to createElement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using node pacakage manager (npm) install fontawesome as a dependency

```
npm install --save react-fontawesome
```

Make sure to import it along with (other dependencies) in this case it's just 'react' on top of the file . Inside your render function you can simply return the statement showing FontAwesome tag to display required font class.

react_fontawesome.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

class ShowFonts extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            <FontAwesome className = 'fa-address-book'
            name = 'address-book'
            size = '4x' / >
        );
    }
}
export default ShowFonts;
```

Inside your main javaScript file(index.js) assuming that your react_fontawesome is in components folder.

```
import ShowFonts from './components/react_fontawesome.js';
```

Finally you can add fontawesome CSS inside your project [Here](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/) is the CDN.

**Note: As described [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome) This component does not include any of the Font Awesome CSS , so you'll need to make sure to include it on your end**

You can read more details about fontaswesome [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome)

Comment: You have a typo in your code, `imort` instead of `import`.

Comment: but I don't know how I can put this code in **React.createElement('span', {className: ''}** ? I have to use **React.createElement** and put fontawesome in span

Comment: Someone help me ?

Comment: Just put `Fontawesome` in place of `¡`. `React.createElement` can take both a tag name or a component name.

Comment: render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement('span', {className: ''},
        React.createElement(<FontAwesome className='fa-address-book'/>)
 });   It  doesn't work

Comment: maybe someone example ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave a comment, so I'll write one more answer...

HTML

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      React.createElement('span', {className: ''},
        React.createElement('i', {className:'fa fa-address-book'})
      )
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```